how to make scrollable dropdown list in combobox customtkinter?
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

root = customtkinter.CTk()
global combo_box
#adding combobox to root
combo_box = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(root, values=["Java", "CSS", "Python", "PHP", "HTML","C#","JavaScript","Ruby","C","C++"])
combo_box.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

#add tab completer event in combobox
def on_tab_complete(event):
    available_options = ["Java", "CSS", "Python"]
    current_text = combo_box.get()
    completions = [option for option in available_options if option.lower().startswith(current_text.lower())]
    if completions:
        combo_box.configure(values=completions)
    else:
        combo_box.configure(values=(" "))

def call_on_tab_complete_twice(event):
    on_tab_complete(event)
    root.after(10, lambda: on_tab_complete(event))

combo_box.bind("<KeyPress>", call_on_tab_complete_twice)

root.mainloop()

that is my code. i want my combobox list have a scrollbar but i don't know how to do it in customtkinter, can someone help me?

you can do the job with this code :
import tkinter as tk

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

root = customtkinter.CTk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=200)  # Adjust the height as needed
canvas.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw")

combo_box = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(frame, values=["Java", "CSS", "Python", "PHP", "HTML", "C#", "JavaScript", "Ruby", "C", "C++"])
combo_box.pack(fill="x")

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

def on_tab_complete(event):
    available_options = ["Java", "CSS", "Python"]
    current_text = combo_box.get()
    completions = [option for option in available_options if option.lower().startswith(current_text.lower())]
    if completions:
        combo_box.configure(values=completions)
    else:
        combo_box.configure(values=(" "))

def call_on_tab_complete_twice(event):
    on_tab_complete(event)
    root.after(10, lambda: on_tab_complete(event))

combo_box.bind("<KeyPress>", call_on_tab_complete_twice)

root.mainloop()


I've found on this link that this feature has been discontinued due to performance issues on certain OS. But from the link you can download the source file for the library used to create scrollable dropdowns as well as code examples.
Hope this helps :)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
